# Explanation of cascade.xml in a haar classifier

Tags: opencv, classification, adaboost, haar-wavelet

It would be best if someone could explain the numbers/values in the cascade.xml entirely.
Example in:

```
<!-- stage 0 -->
<_>
  <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
  <stageThreshold>-8.8384145498275757e-001</stageThreshold>
  <weakClassifiers>
    <_>
      <internalNodes>
        0 -1 66 5.1593100652098656e-003</internalNodes>
      <leafValues>
        -8.0555558204650879e-001 8.0694979429244995e-001</leafValues></_>
    <_>
      <internalNodes>
        0 -1 108 1.5044789761304855e-002</internalNodes>
      <leafValues>
        -6.2940740585327148e-001 7.5122624635696411e-001</leafValues></_>
    <_>
      <internalNodes>
        0 -1 99 -4.7172707127174363e-005</internalNodes>
      <leafValues>
        5.5112153291702271e-001 -8.6111217737197876e-001</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
```

What are the meanings of these values

```
      <internalNodes>
        0 -1 99 -4.7172707127174363e-005</internalNodes>
```

Another question is, how does the program know which feature to use for a particular stage?
As far as I know, features are in the form as below

```
<_>
  <rects>
    <_>
      21 6 3 5 -1.</_>
    <_>
      22 6 1 5 3.</_></rects>
  <tilted>0</tilted></_>
```

Whereby it's the coordinates of two rectangles, forming something like below:

```
=-=    = Black colored rectangle
=-=    - White colored rectangle
=-=
=-=
=-=
```

What are the values -1. and 3. mean? I know it's weights but how is it used to calculate the feature?

**Summary**

1. What are the meaning of the values inside `<internalNodes>`?
2. How is the feature calculated? How are the weights in `<rects>` use?
3. Most importantly, which field denotes that which features are being used in a particular stage/node.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482123/whats-inside-a-haar-cascade-classifier-in-open-cv-computer-vision

Comment: @AbidRahmanK thanks for the link. FYI i have already read that before posting this. It doesn't provide any answers to my questions.

Comment: @Alvin Have you understood the <internalNodes> mean. It has four values when trainning with HAAE-like features. And  It has 11 values when trainning with HAAE-like features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging into OpenCV's source code, I finally obtain answers to my own questions.

- Values enclosed withtin internalNodes tags

> node.left node.right node.featureIdx node.threshold

I'm not sure what's node.left and node.right are for as I can't see them being called anywhere.

- The weights are used to calculate the feature as in below:

> float ret = rect[0].weight * CALC_SUM(p[0], _offset) + rect[1].weight * CALC_SUM(p[1], _offset);

- As mentioned in the first bullet, the node.featureIdx are the index of the feature that's being evaluated at that particular node.