# Haar Cascade XML

Tags: xml, face-detection, haar-classifier

I am interested in what everything in the xml file below means:

```
<stages>
<trees>
<feature>
<rects>
<_>
<tilted>
<threshold>
<left_val>
<right_val>
```

and what the five integers in between rects mean.

```
        <feature>
          <rects>
            <_>
              14 18 1 2 -1.</_>
            <_>
              14 19 1 1 2.</_></rects>
          <tilted>0</tilted></feature>
        <threshold>-4.3883759644813836e-005</threshold>
        <left_val>0.3130159080028534</left_val>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you are making this a bit harder than it has to be, but I'll try. I guess, you are asking about object detectors in OpnenCV. These are *cascades* of boosted classifiers which originate from [Viola&Jones face detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) which classify each image region/patch into object/background classes and are called *scanning window object detectors*.

- `<stages>` is a series of more and more complex classifiers which try identify if an image patch contains a face (with higher and higher confidence).
- `<trees>` should be even simpler classifiers which the stages are composed of.
- `<feature>` is a simple hand-coded feature which extracts single value from an image.
- `<rects>` are rectangular regions a feature is composed of.
- `<tilted>` could be a binary value - if the *feature* is 45° rotated.
- `<threshod>` is a threhold of the value of the *feature*.
- `<left_val>` is a *vote* about the *probability* that the *classified* region contains face if the value of the feature is below the `<threshold>`.
- `<right_val>` is a *vote* about the *probability* that the *classified* region contains face if the value of the feature is above the `<threshold>`.

PS: I could be wrong, I did my Ph.D. on this type of classifiers, I did not write OpenCV.

Comment: Hello Michal thank you so much. Just to clarify what exactly is the threshold and how would you calculate if there is a face in the feature? Also I was wondering what do the integers in between the rects mean!
Thank you very much!

Comment: The threshold is after each "feature" and thresholds its response into left_val and right_val. Those left/right votes are summed and the sum is a confidence of the classifier. Each stage classifier has a final threshold and the region must pass through all stages to be considered a face. For exact details, it is better to read the wiki or the original paper. The <rects> contain probably xy position, width, height and multiplication value. I don't know the exact answer and you'll probably would have to look at the source code. BTW OpenCV has at least one more format for these detectors.

Comment: Thank you again! I have scoured the internet and couldn’t find the relevant source code that explains what the rects mean?

Comment: Some info on <rects> is in previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482123/whats-inside-a-haar-cascade-classifier-in-open-cv-computer-vision?rq=1